# get another xml value located in another path using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to convert input XML to output XML. Similarly XML conversion using xslt.

input xml and supporing xml files are in local path(same path only).

XSl and saxon9.jar is in server path.

output xml will be created in local path(same as input xml path).

using xslt2.0 i can get an input xml values but not able to get the supporting xml values(present in local)

d:\test>java -jar saxon9.jar -s:"d:\Tools\MasterRefs.xml" -xsl:"IOP-NEW.xsl" -o:"d:\Tools\out.xml"

Below is my xsl for getting values from supporting.xml

< xsl:variable name="fpath" select="document('supporting.xml')" />

<journal-title>

<xsl:value-of select="$fpath/item-info/titles/journal-title"/>

</journal-title>

Can anyone help me for this...

Answer (score 0):

Try `<xsl:variable name="fpath" select="document('supporting.xml', /)"/>` to resolve the relative URI `'supporting.xml'` with the main input document (`/`) providing the base URI.